# Изучение Android-программирования

Tags: android, книги

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть желание изучить программирование под Android, имеются базовые знания java. Посоветуйте как лучше изучать? Денег много не имею, поэтому дорогие курсы не подойдут, напишите, по каким книгам или видеокурсам изучать.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Можете начать изучение с этой статьи:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/328888/

Answer (score 3):

[startandroid.ru](http://startandroid.ru/ru/)

Answer (score 1):

[Программирование под ОС Android](http://metanit.com/java/android/)

Answer (score 1):

очень хорошая книга: Брайн Харди , Билл Филлипс - Программирование под Android - 2014

Answer (score 0):

Начать можно [вот с этого.](http://learn-android.ru/)